How i find the key for firebase Messaging Cloud
I can´t find the server key, when i tried to use i recive a LogCat (my application work with kotlin and Android Studio like that:"E  Error: Status Code 401, Data: 

INVALID_KEY



INVALID_KEY
Error 401

"

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It is no longer possible to use a server key to send messages through Firebase Cloud Messaging.
You will nowadays needs to use Google Application Default Credentials, a service account JSON file, or a short-lived OAuth2 access token derived from a service account to authorize requests. See the Firebase documentation for full details on how to do this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server
Also see these topics in the Firebase FAQ:

Which FCM APIs were deprecated on June 20, 2023, and what should I do if I am using those APIs?
Can new projects enable the legacy Cloud Messaging API?

